# Will SQLite Work in a ClickOnce Deployment?

Tags: .net, wpf, sqlite, clickonce

And if it will, what is the best practice in terms of connection strings? Just a relative path? |DataDirectory| ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQ Lite should work just fine in a ClickOnce scenario.  It's a zero configuration components.  Components which require configuration usually have issues with click once.

http://www.sqlite.org/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about SQLite, but yes: I believe you'd want to use `|DataDirectory|` with ClickOnce, since that points to the area in the user's profile where the app's data/settings can be stored.

Comment: it's actually SqLite (only 1 l).  I spent about 5 minutes googling for sqllite and only found the real website due to a typo.