# WPF Application deployment - Problem with Application starting in another PC

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment

All,

I have a WPF application built upon SQLite database and user/application Configuration settings. The application builds and runs fine in development environment. I created a Setup and Deployment project, added the "Project output" of above said application and then proceeded to create a setup. The pre-requisites and the .NET Framework versions are same in the Application and in the setup project:

.NET Framework 3.5 Client Profile
MS Visual Basic Powerpacks 10.0.0
Windows Installer 3.1

But when I move it onto another PC with identical .NET Framework installed (but without the development environment), the application does not start. It gives a "has encountered a problem and needs to close" Error. I found that this would mean a uncaught exception in the application. So, I tried to comment out parts of the application that did not have them handled and left all but a single window to display (the Main window that does nothing) but yet the application fails. I begin to suspect that the problem could be that the dependancies are not handled for the app start. Here is what I did with them:

1. SQLite needed a DLL that is automatically added to the "Detected Dependencies" It gets copied to the Application Directory
2. SQLite databases are added manually to the project and they are copied to the Application Directory
3. The Application.exe.config files are NOT copied. I am not sure where to put them

At this point, I would like to know how I can find out the root-cause for the problem. I tried running another simple app with a single window (and no functionality) and it works on the target machine. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think the problem lies in the dependencies then it might be worth having a look at the ["Assembly Binding Log Viewer"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) (i.e. fuslogvw.exe). This tool should be able to tell you exactly which assemblies were requested and how the requests were satisfied, or not satisfied. The catch is that this only works for managed assemblies.

If however you want to find out what the unhandled exception is then you could wrap a try .. catch around the application entry point. The catch in WPF is that this is generated by the compiler / Visual Studio so you can't normally change it. If you do want to change it, say to put a try .. catch around it then you need to (example taken from http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2008/09/how_to_write_custom_main_metho.html):

1. Find the App.xaml and App.xaml.cs files
2. Open the property page for App.xaml and change the build action to 'Page'
3. In App.xaml.cs add a Main() method which should look like:

   ```cs
   [STAThread]
   public static void Main()
   {
       var app = new App();
       app.InitializeComponent();
       app.Run();
   }
   ```

If you wrap a try .. catch around the entire method body then you could write what ever the error information is to a text file. Hopefully that will help you find out what is wrong.

===== EDIT =====

If the unhandled exception is not being caught by the try .. catch construct then it can be a binder problem. Because the JIT compiler compiles methods on a as-needed basis it may help to move nearly all code out of the entry method. For example:

```
<!-- language: lang-cs -->

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            MyMethod();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // ... Write to file here
        }
    }

    private static void MyMethod()
    {
        // .. Do actual work here
    }
```

By doing this you make sure that you are inside the try .. catch construct before the run-time tries to locate the right assemblies etc. However note that there are some exceptions that can't be caught (OutOfMemoryException, StackOverflowException and some others).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will certainly try out the latter Exception handling fix and see the results. I will let you know the results later

Comment: Petrik, I tried running the application with the manually written main() method wrapped around a try { .. } but it did not help. So, if its not a unhandled exception, could it one of the dependencies? I am still unsure how to package the database files and the config files (application_name.exe.config) files in the installer. Could you point me to where I could find more material on adding databases and config files to setup projects?

Comment: Does the application get to the code inside the try .. catch loop? It could be that the problem occurs before your code is even loaded. In that case it could be a dependency problem. The fusion log viewer should be able to help you with that.

Comment: As for the installer, I guess the easiest way to check is to compare the install directory with the build directory. The easiest way to do that is to make a copy of the bin/release directory (if you can run the app from there), copy that over to the other machine (say to c:\temp\myapp) and then compare that directory with the directory where you installed the app. That should show you if anything is missing.

Comment: Petrik, Thanks for your patience. I was finally able to obtain some logs from the application run environment when I put the try { ... } catch around the windows initialization methods. It seems that there are some XAML parse exceptions that I need to handle. Strange that I do not encounter these problems during compile time or build time. Anyway, I am now marking your answer as solution. If I need more help, I will post a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the **ClickOnce** deployment option for your application?

As you can see from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532251/will-sqlite-work-in-a-clickonce-deployment) it should be possible to **bundle your SQLite DB with a ClickOnce application**. You would get other benefits (if you are interested) such as automatic updates.

Comment: I have tried ClickOnce deployment with the same results.  I am still unsure how to package the database files and the config files (application_name.exe.config) files in the installer. Could you point me to where I could find more material on adding databases and config files to setup projects?

Answer (score 0):

The problem also occurs if you changed the namespace of App.xaml.cs, but not of App.xaml. The moment you add the code above, you will know, since the InitializeComponent() call will not compile.